# Joining with a column of type varchar that has both string and numbers stored in it

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

I have a column in my table of type `varchar(50)` that stores both words and ids.
For example there are values such as: `50, 95, Example, Testing....`

When `NOT ISNUMERIC(column)`, I can just use the value. When `ISNUMERIC(column)`, I need to join with another table to get the value that is supposed to be selected.

I got the `SELECT` part down:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(column) = 1 THEN othertable.Name ELSE column END
```

Now I am trying to only `JOIN` under the same scenario:

```
LEFT JOIN OtherTable ot ON CAST(column AS INT) = t.Id
```

This will not work because the `CAST` will not work when column is a word. I really only need to join if column is a number.

I am not a fan of using 1 column to store 2 different datatypes but I took over an existing database so I don't really have a choice.

Comment: You have to do it  the ISNUMERIC in the ON...

Comment: I can do a CASE statement in the ON?

Comment: do you have only numbers in `ID` ?

Comment: What is `t` and what is `ot`?  Why is there no `ot` in the `on` clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case it is better to cast `int` to `varchar` then the other way round:

```
 LEFT JOIN OtherTable ot ON column = cast(t.Id as varchar(10))
```

Comment: Not sure how or why I didn't think about this but thank you for the excellent answer!!

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those rare cases where a `case` in the `on` clause might make sense.  Assuming you really mean:

```
LEFT JOIN OtherTable ot ON CAST(column AS INT) = ot.Id
```

Then this can theoretically use an index on `othertable.id`.

Similarly, the following could use can index:

```
LEFT JOIN OtherTable ot
ON ot.id = (case when isnumeric(column) = 1 then CAST(column AS INT) end);
```

If you cast `ot.id`, then the query cannot use an index on that column.